# Getting error Invalid state change requested in Magento2.2

Tags: plugin, magento2.2, magento-2.1.9

When I am placing order by my payment gateway I am getting error `Invalid state change requested`. I debug the core code and found that is error is coming from plugin used by core classes. i.e `Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Plugin\AccessChangeQuoteControl` which is not exist in previous version of magento2 (i.e before Magento2.2) . Have anyone idea what is purpose of this plugin.

Comment: The plugin checks if the user has ability to change the quote

Comment: yes bro i know this but why this is checking for access and what parameter will affect it and also how we can control it

Comment: @YogeshKarodiya did you manage to solve this problem? We've got the same type of issue with one of our Magento 2.2.1 stores.

Comment: @Tjitse I have solved this issue by removing quote repository from my payment file which I was previously using for get quote. So check in your payment file where you are using quote object.

Comment: From which file i need to remove @YogeshKarodiya can you please tell me,  I am having same issue based on authorize.net payment gatway

Comment: As suggested by @keyur this error generally comes when plugin shares a quote. so you can debug your plugin where you are using a quote object.

Comment: Wah sir ji :) @YogeshKarodiya